# Can Stripe change the payment intent status between the confirm payment call, if successful, and the webhook they send me?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a social app where my customer is going to make single purchases (credits/tokens/likes) using a credit card (Visa, Master, Amex, Discover). When the purchase is complete, and I receive a "succeeded" in the result "status" from the Stripe result, the customer will then be given 10, 20, 50, 100, etc. tokens to their profile that can be used now for "liking" someone.

**FYI** - If the user has a card saved and chooses that card, that Stripe card number and customer number is used for the payment intent, otherwise I'm collecting the card details, and passing that to the "confirmpayment()".

**QUESTION** - Once I call Stripe "confirmpayment()" client side, and get the result back, which shows the status (succeeded, failed, incomplete, etc.) Is it possible to receive a "succeeded" status in the result and then at some later date via Stripe's webhook, receive a different status other than "succeeded"?

**FYI** - I've gone through almost all [test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) scenarios to test for this type of condition, but it doesn't seem like it will happen? It seems like the payment will either succeed or fail on the confirmpayment() call. I'm also double checking the status result on the server side by fetching the paymentIntent from Stripe. Just to make sure the user (client side) hasn't changed it in the code (JS/Typescript).

**Concern** - The customer finishes their purchase, the confirmpayment result shows a status of "succeeded", their "tokens" are added to their profile at that moment and then they proceed to use them to send "likes" to another user. Then later on I get the Stripe webhook back showing a different status with "failed" or "incomplete". But by this point, "tokens" will have been used and a monetary amount based on the amount of the "token" will have been moved from my Connect account where the original purchased fund will be sent to the intended receiver's connect account. If this happens I foresee it being extremely difficult to back all this out and reverse it will out a huge headache.

**ALTERNATIVE WORKFLOW** - I could create a "payment" entity on the server side with a pending status and wait until I receive the Stripe webhook before I add any "tokens" to the user account/profile. This will insure there is no possibility for error, but it makes the user wait until the webhook comes in before they will see a status of "success" on their payment page and won't be able to use any "tokens" from that purchase until I get the webhook. I wanted to give them a more instant experience.

Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you get back after the Promise `confirmCardPayment()` resolves will be the same as the status you get back on the webhook event so it will never be that a `succeeded` PaymentIntent transitions back to `requires_payment_method` or `requires_action`, as `succeeded` is an end state of the lifecycle.

Keep in mind, webhook events can be out of order, so technically you could get a `payment_intent.requires_action` *after* your `payment_intent.succeeded` event (if they happen very quickly.

The best thing to do is to fetch the PaymentIntent from the API (after an event) to get the "true" state of the PaymentIntent.

Comment: Hi hmunoz. Thanks for the response. My concern is that I call stripes confirmpayment() on the client side before I add any new entity on my server side, confirmpayment() passes, then I call up my controller to create my server side "payment" entity. I add all the data to it, but then when I save it to the DB it fails. So I'm stuck with charging my customers card with Stripe, but don't have the correct record of it on my side resulting in a big problem. Con't in next post...

Comment: So I'm thinking maybe a better flow would be, when the customer submits, to first create my "payment" entity with all the payment intent info (amount, intent id, etc) with a status of pending in my DB. Then I return to the client, call Stripes confirmpayment() and get the result back. If it passes or fails it doesn't matter, I will call the server controller again, and on my server side I will fetch Stripes Paymentintent() data and update the "payment" entity with whatever Stripe gives me and I'm done! I guess I really don't need to listen for any webhook for this pass/fail payment event?

Comment: I'd do all that and listen to webhooks. I say that because there is a case where the payment succeeds on the client but before your page can post to your server, the customer closes the webpage, so your server never hears about it. You should still listen to webhooks as a fall back and build redundancy on your end.

Comment: OH! Never thought about that! Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Hi HMunoz. One last question - Would it be possible to confirm the payment on the client side with Stripe and then receive the webhook on the server side before I have time for the user to post back to the controller to finish the payment? Or put another way, can the webhook be sent immediately or does it wait for some time before it's sent to the url hook?

Comment: both those scenarios are possible yes. Your webhook could come before or after your client is able to post to your backend, so you should build redundancy both ways, on your backend.

Comment: Hi HMunoz. That seems like a horrible solution, because now I could end up with exceptions (unique paymentIntentId collision) being thrown very frequently. The exception would be a "Payment" entity that I'm trying to insert into the DB that already exists. If I should create that redundancy to insert the "Payment" entity on both the post back and the webhook this could be really overly complicated to implement and could lead to a large number of exceptions being thrown, which would not be good.

Comment: I meant that both approaches (post from client vs webhook event) should check if your database has that PaymentIntent ID first, and if not, only then add it to your database.

Comment: Right I understand, but if they both get called and both check for that id and both return nothing/null. Then both will attempt to create a new "Payment" entity. When they try to save to the DB, one will succeed and the other will fail (throw exception). This could cause a shit ton of exceptions to be thrown. Not good?

Comment: You should leverage a queue in your backend, where you only allow serially updating your database so that the above scenario isn't possible. Both the post from client, and the webhook event would both go into a FIFO queue where you process whichever came first (i.e. look up the database and insert if needed)

Comment: Do you have any examples you can send me a link to check out, or is this just some idea your throwing out there, as I've never heard of this.

Comment: It is just a general programming principle to queue events and process them as they come in, it isn't Stripe related but often used for webhook events (regardless of Stripe).

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52158728/10654456